# Lambda capture 'this' saved as std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

The following code is compiled OK with C++14, but running it results in segmentation fault. Is this caused by the lambda function capture (commented with question mark)? What is the proper way to do it? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Process {
    Process(std::function<void()> &processFunc) 
        : processFunc(processFunc) {}
    void doit() {
        processFunc();  // causes segmentation fault
    }

    std::function<void()> &processFunc;
};

struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        std::function<void()> func = [this](){this->process();}; // ?
        p = std::make_unique<Process>(func);
    }
    void process() {std::cout << "Done.\n";}
    void start() {p->doit();}
    std::unique_ptr<Process> p;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.start();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The segmentation fault occurs because the `std::function` object to which `Process::processFunc` refers is destroyed when the `Foo` constructor returns. To solve this problem, make `Process` retain a copy of the `std::function` object.

```
struct Process {
    Process(const std::function<void()>& processFunc) 
        : processFunc(processFunc) {}
    // ...
    std::function<void()> processFunc;
};
```

Comment: @ArnavBorborah yes

Comment: Well, you might want to consider adding that this is caused by a dangling reference in your answer, just for completeness.

Comment: @JiveDadson I don't see how the rule of five applies here. I would say this is a "rule of zero" class, in fact.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't look carefully enough. I thought the constructor was a copy-constructor.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.